# Is the to_delete parameter required in my code to extract from BigQuery to GCS?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have written some code to extract from BigQuery to a GCS Bucket, using the Google Cloud Docs, and I am unsure whether the `to_delete` parameter is required in my code.

I have not tried anything yet, as I am unsure what I would replace the parameter with.

This is my code:

```
def extract_table(client, to_delete):
    bucket_name = "extract_mytable_{}".format(_millis())
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = retry_storage_errors(storage_client.create_bucket)(bucket_name)
    to_delete.append(bucket)

    # [START bigquery_extract_table]
    # from google.cloud import bigquery
    # client = bigquery.Client()
    # bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
    project = "bigquery-public-data"
    dataset_id = "samples"
    table_id = "mytable"

    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "mytable.csv")
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        # Location must match that of the source table.
        location="US",
    )  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to export a `BigQuery` table to `GCS`, I think no need a param like `to_delete`.

You may also use a built in `Airflow` operator to execute the same code as you shown in your question but with `BigQueryToGCSOperator` operator :

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToGCSOperator


bigquery_to_gcs = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
    task_id='bq_to_gsc_task',
    compression='NONE',
    export_format='CSV',
    field_delimiter=',',
    print_header=True,
    source_project_dataset_table=f'{your_dataset}.{your_table}',
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=[
        f'gs://{your_bucket_name}/{your_output_filename}.csv',
    ],
)
```

The [BigQueryToGCSOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html) allows executing the same code more simply.

Comment: @dr-leo-smith-davison have you solved your issue ?